# Segmentation Fault on OpenGL application with GLAD and GLFW3 (openGL 4.1/pureC/MacOS)

Tags: c, opengl, makefile, glfw, glad

I'm trying to learn OpenGL and C by following the learnopengl.com tutorial and the JDAH series of videos about OpenGL in C. I especially got really inspired by this project of him : [minecraft in one week](https://github.com/jdah/minecraft-weekend).

I had a perfectly working code up until the lighting chapter of learnopengl.com but my code was messy and I wanted to refactor and clean up so I changed the Makefile to JDAH's one, split the code in several files. Nothing is working anymore.

I've spent the past 7 hours trying to debug this and I'm learning that debugging segfault in C is not that fun. Anyway, I think I pinpointed the problem, it seems that my second call to `glEnableVertexAttribArray` dereference a null pointer which creates the segfault. I tried changing Glew to Glad. I reinstalled the libs, tried make changes to the Makefile but nothing worked, I'm losing hope.

Below you can find my Makefile, a part of my main.c and a picture of the segfault as shown in lldb. I'm running on MacOS 13.2, and using OpenGL 4.1. I have Glew installed in my /usr/local/include but it's not those that are referenced by the makefile, I don't know if that can cause problems.

JDAH's code run perfectly on my Mac with almost the same Makefile (didn't include noise), but he uses OpenGL 3.3 and I use OpenGL 4.1 so I changed the glad folder.

**Makefile**

```
UNAME_S = $(shell uname -s)

CC = clang
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-gnu-statement-expression
CFLAGS += -Wno-gnu-compound-literal-initializer -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments
CFLAGS += -Ilib/cglm/include -Ilib/glad/include -Ilib/glfw/include -Ilib/stb -fbracket-depth=1024
LDFLAGS = lib/glad/src/glad.o lib/cglm/libcglm.a lib/glfw/src/libglfw3.a -lm

# GLFW required frameworks on OSX
ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
    LDFLAGS += -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -framework Cocoa
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Linux)
    LDFLAGS += -ldl -lpthread
endif

SRC  = $(wildcard src/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/**/*.c)
OBJ  = $(SRC:.c=.o)
BIN = bin

.PHONY: all clean

all: dirs libs game

libs:
    cd lib/cglm && cmake . -DCGLM_STATIC=ON && make
    cd lib/glad && $(CC) -o src/glad.o -Iinclude -c src/glad.c
    cd lib/glfw && cmake . && make

dirs:
    mkdir -p ./$(BIN)

run: all
    $(BIN)/game

game: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN)/game $^ $(LDFLAGS)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJ)
```

**main.c** (there is more code but I didn't include all for the sake of readability. LLDB is crashing on the SECOND glEnableVertexArray)

```
#include "glad/glad.h"
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include "GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cglm/cglm.h>

#include "gfx/shaders.h"


#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>

int main() {

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        printf("Error initializing GLFW");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); 

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    if (window == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create Window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback); 
    
    int version = gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);
    if (version == 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize OpenGL context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Successfully loaded OpenGL
    printf("Loaded OpenGL %d.%d\n", GLVersion.major, GLVersion.minor);
    printf("test");
    printf("%s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("test");

    //Enable Depth Buffer
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    //Define viewport for the size of the window
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);



    //Generate a VAO so we don't have to do this configuration for every vertices
    unsigned int VAO, VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);  
    //Get Vertex Buffer Object from OpenGL
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);  
    //Push vertex data into the buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

**Output of LLDB**

Since I'm new at C I might have forgotten something, feel free to ask for more information, I'll do my best to provide them.

```
(lldb) n
Process 28686 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x000000010000a990 game`main at main.c:238:5 [opt]
   235      glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)0);
   236      glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
   237      glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
-> 238      glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
   239 
   240 
   241      unsigned int vertexShader;
Target 0: (game) stopped.
(lldb) n
Process 28686 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x00007ffa20fc4f00
->  0x7ffa20fc4f00: movl   (%rax), %edi
    0x7ffa20fc4f02: popq   %rbp
    0x7ffa20fc4f03: jmpq   *%r8
    0x7ffa20fc4f06: pushq  %rbp
Target 0: (game) stopped.
```

**EDIT 1**
I tried to follow [Haris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20017547/haris) input and catch error codes. The results are weird and I don't really understand everything. I'm logging the version of OpenGL after GLAD loading, this is the lines of code involved :

```
    // Successfully loaded OpenGL
    printf("Loaded OpenGL %d.%d\n", GLVersion.major, GLVersion.minor);
    GLenum err;
    err = glGetError();
    printf("Error: %u", err);
    printf("%s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    err = glGetError();
    printf("Error2: %u", err);
```

Since LLDB is going through those lines without complaining I assumed that they were not a problem, but in fact, only the first printf in the console. This observation is true for every printf after that. I tried to `glGetError()` after every function call, but nothing appears in the console.

**Console Output**

```
Loaded OpenGL 4.1
[1]    31313 segmentation fault  bin/game
```

**Edit 2**

I tried to change error handling so it looks like this as [Haris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20017547/haris) pointed out.

```
    // Successfully loaded OpenGL
    printf("Loaded OpenGL %d.%d\n", GLVersion.major, GLVersion.minor);
    if(!glGetString(GL_VERSION)) {
        err = glGetError();
        printf("Error %u", err);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("TEST");

    err = glGetError();
    printf("Error2: %u", err);
```

As for [Derhass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2327517/derhass) request, you can find bellow the rest of my main.c. It was working perfectly fine yesterday before I started changing makefile and libs.

```
   glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)));
    err = glGetError();
    printf("%u", err);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    err = glGetError();
    printf("%u", err);

    unsigned int vertexShader;
    unsigned int fragmentShaderOrange = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER); // the first fragment shader that outputs the color orange
    unsigned int shaderProgramOrange = glCreateProgram();

    //const char* vertexShaderSourceFromFile = getShader(BASE_VERTEX_SHADER);

    compile_shader(&vertexShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, BASE_VERTEX_SHADER);
    compile_shader(&fragmentShaderOrange, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, BASE_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    // link the first program object
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramOrange, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgramOrange, fragmentShaderOrange);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgramOrange);
    // then link the second program object using a different fragment shader (but same vertex shader)
    // this is perfectly allowed since the inputs and outputs of both the vertex and fragment shaders are equally matched.

    unsigned int texture1;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load and generate the texture
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);  
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load("./res/tibo.jpg", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to load texture.");
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    unsigned int texture2;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    // set the texture wrapping/filtering options (on the currently bound texture object)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);   
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    data = stbi_load("./res/awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgramOrange);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramOrange, "texture1"), 0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramOrange, "texture2"), 1);


    //#FREE RAM
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderOrange);

    mat4 projection;
    glm_perspective(glm_rad(45.0f), 800.0f / 600.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);

    unsigned  int projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramOrange, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, projection[0]);


    // uncomment this call to draw in wireframe polygons.
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        processInput(window);

        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame; 

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgramOrange);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        vec3 cameraTarget;
        glm_vec3_add(cameraFront, cameraPos, cameraTarget);

        mat4 view;
        glm_lookat(
            cameraPos,
            cameraTarget,
            cameraUp,
            view);

        unsigned  int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramOrange, "view");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, view[0]);

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mat4 model;
            glm_mat4_identity(model);
            glm_translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
            glm_rotate(model, glm_rad(20.0f * i), (vec3){1.0f, 0.3f, 0.5f});


            unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramOrange, "model");
            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, model[0]);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        }

        
        //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();    
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 3**

I tried some more old school methods of debugging, aka commenting every line of code and decommenting them one by one until I see the crash. I got something new, a `38900 bus error  bin/game`when calling the functions I wrote to compile shaders.
Those functions read shaders from files, pass them as strings to GLSL that compiles them and returns them.

You can see below the snippet of code that does that. It was working great before my refactoring and I made sure to update my paths when I moved the files

```
void compile_shader(GLuint* shaderId, GLenum shaderType, int shaderFilePath)
{
    GLint isCompiled = 0;
    /* Calls the Function that loads the Shader source code from a file */
    const char* shaderSource = getShader(shaderFilePath); 

    *shaderId = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    if(*shaderId == 0) {
        printf("COULD NOT LOAD SHADER: %d!\n", shaderFilePath);
    }

    glShaderSource(*shaderId, 1, (const char**)&shaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shaderId);
    glGetShaderiv(*shaderId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled);

    if(isCompiled == GL_FALSE) { /* Here You should provide more error details to the User*/
        printf("Shader Compiler Error: %d\n", shaderFilePath);
        glDeleteShader(*shaderId);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do none of those functions return an error code? If they do, why do you not check for them?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with debugging in C yet, I imagined that if the function raised a "readable" error it would be shown on the console, but I guess it's not that simple. How could I "read" those error code in an understandable way ?

Comment: See post edit, I'm confused by the C experience haha

Comment: Yeah, I tried to use the code on that page, but with no success it seems

Comment: I'm skeptical that the crash happens where the debugger shows you. I'd really have a look at the code afterwards.

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to get skeptical about literally everything with this matter. See edit of original post for the whole main.c

Comment: Absolutely not, I tried several tweaks, changing order, calling different functions, while staying close to what I can see on the links you sent me, but nothing worked. Even just printing "TEST" doesn't work

Comment: I'll do that ! I tried to run the code with the minimal lines in it, and I can see a black screen, I take that as a good sign, I'll try to add line by line of codes to see where it crashes. I'll probably continue tomorrow tho.

Comment: First of all, OpenGL (And most likely any library you'll ever use in C) never print errors. They just return you a code or set it internally and wait for you to check it. In this case, you're looking for `glGetError` after each of your `gl`* calls. Second, do yourself a favor and use `gdb`, or just about any debugger supporting backtracing. You won't achieve much in C otherwise.

Comment: In the line of the error: `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (void*)(3*sizeof(float)))`, shouldn't it be `sizeof(GLfloat)`? If I record well, GL_FLOAT is a constant, not a data type.

Comment: @AggelosT I figured that using a debugger would ease my task indeed. I tried gdb, but I get `During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.`everytime, even if I set breakpoint, but maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: @CarlHR Hmm, I'm not sure about GL_FLOAT, but GlFloat is an unknown identifier during compilation, not sure what it means

Comment: `sizeof(GL_FLOAT)` is definitely wrong. Use `sizeof(float)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 will do ! I might have found another source of bug. I'm reading my shaders from files, and the files I'm parsing are not in the same directory as the source code reading them, maybe I have some I/O problems ?

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved. I'm definitely a newbie in C and the issue was nothing more that relative path that were relative to the source code and not relative to where I ran the code. I'm still amazed that a simple error like that made me want to think my life choices over, but I'm happy now that this bug is solved.

I have the greatest respect for my fellow pure C developper, coding in a language that support good debugging is clearly coding in easy mode.